# Passing 'Stream' to client throws error

Tags: c#, http, serialization, soap, stream

Below struct is serializable and when server (runs WCF web service) returns object of this then client can properly receives data.

```
[Serializable]
public struct TestInfo
{
    public string TestStr;
    public int TestInt;
}
```

Scenario: Server is trying to open endpoint and send it to client, so that client will write file into it. I tried adding 'Stream' in struct like below but it is throws error.

```
[Serializable]
public struct TestInfo
{
    public string TestStr;
    public int TestInt;
    public Stream TestStream;
}
```

Error:

```
An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response. 
This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. 
This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). 
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: 
An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> 
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: 
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)

at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)

at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)

at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartReading(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)

at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)

at System.Net.TlsStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)

at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)

at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

at     System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Any idea if I am missing anything here ? 'Stream' is serializable and I thought it will be fine to send Stream. If 'Stream' is not best way then any other way that I can try ?

Comment: I have no idea why Stream is marked serializable, but essentially none of its actual implementations can be meaningfully serialized. There is really no way to serialize something like local file access (`FileStream`) or local network connection (`NetworkStream`/`SslStream`) in a way that is useful outside of local box.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative way to transfer your file is by converting your file content into byte and add filename data member in you data contract.

```
[DataContract]
public struct TestInfo
{    
    [DataMember]
    public string FileName;   
    [DataMember]
    public byte [] FileStream;
}
```

Write a file in system

```
using(var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
}
```

**Note :** If you notice I change Serializable annotation with [DataContract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792269/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-datacontract-rather-than-serializable-in-wc) because it has a couple of advantages than Serializable. You may also consider this few setting if you want to [pass large data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you really want to pass stream in the pipe there couple of link in the net out other.

Ex.

- [Streaming files over WCF](http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2011/01/streaming-files-over-wcf.html)
- [WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP)

Comment: I actually do not want to transfer file from client to server. I am trying to open file access point at server and trying to send that to client. Then client should write file into that file access point (and not transfer file to server). I refereed second link earlier and that's how I decided to pass stream and got above error. I will try to use [DataContract] or [MessageContract] and see how it works.